# How does the look up function work?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, lookup-column

I currently have two lists:

List #1 have the fields country and colour (and several other fields that are irrelevant)

List #2 have the field colour (and several other fields that are irrelevant)

So in List #1, the country Norway might be connected to the colour green.

I want to perform a lookup on List #1 from list #2, so that the country is included with its corresponding colour. This should be possible with the look up function since there is a connection between those two fields.

Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the type of column colour in List#1 to LookUp.
When you will select the LookUp column, you can select the List#2 in source and column colour

Now your column in List#1 will be connected to List#2's colour column.

Please let me know if you want further explanation.

[Help Link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=574)

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query

Comment: Yes, but this does not automatically put together a country with a colour. Now I have the drop down menu with all the available countries. I want to connect a certain colour with a country, depending on list #1 values. So when you pick the colour green, the country "Norway" will be automatically put together with that colour.